# how to find the set of influential features in clusters?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I have 4 clusters and I need to find the set of most influential features in each cluster so that I can get some insight about the characteristics of the cluster and thus to understand the behavior of these clusters. How can I do this?

Comment: 1. this question if off-topic on SO; 2. this is not a free code-writing service; 3. your question is too broad (that is there might no be any general answer to your question). How this question managed to get 2 up-votes is way beyond my comprehension: it violates every possible SO guideline.

Comment: I will agree with @EliKorvigo on this. There is nothing substantial in this question to be upvoted. The question is too broad. The OP needs to first understand what clustering essentially is, because if you have understood it then you already have the relevant features in the cluster. OP check out "Principal Component Analysis" and/or Multiple Correspondence Analysis. In my opinion, the accepted answer given below is statistically incorrect. Clustering is a preprocessing algorithm & must be used before a classification task and not vice-versa, because then its conceptually nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rudimentary method of addressing the problem is by finding the descriptive statistics for the features of the cluster centroids.

Snippet to find the most influencing variables:

```
var_influence=cc.describe() #cc contains the cluster centroids 
# The descriptive statistics of the cluster centroids are saved in a Dataframe var_influence. 
# Sorting by standard deviation will give the variables with high standard deviation.
var_influence.sort_values(axis=1, by='std', ascending=False).iloc[:,:10]
```

This way it is quicker and better to find the influencing variables when compared to the box plot way (Which is hard to visualise with increasing features). As all the variables are normalised it is very easy to compare across features.

A max-min approach can also be used, this will allow us to see the variables with maximum bandwidth. As all the variables are normalised the max-min is a good way to validate the above result.Code for the same below

```
pd.Series(var_influence.loc['max']-var_influence.loc['min']).sort_values(ascending=False)[:10]
```

**Multiclass classification**

A more serious approach to find the influencing features is **Multi-class classification**: The cluster labels are used as a target variable to train a multi-class classification model on the data. The resulting model coefficients can be used to determine the importance of the features.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I use is to train a classifier to predict each cluster label (1 if the corresponding cluster, 0 else), and then use the model attributes to determine the most discriminating variables per cluster. I've been doing that with RandomForest and the attribute feature_importances_ in sickit learn and I always got very good results.

I then use boxplots / density plots to represent the distributions of those variables per cluster.

You can also more traditional approaches, like comparing the means by cluster for each variable, and use statistical tests like ANOVA to get more reliable results.

Edit: Here is an example in Python :

```
for cl in data.cluster.unique():


    custom_target = data.cluster.copy()
    custom_target.loc[custom_target != cl] = -1
    custom_target.loc[custom_target == cl] = 1

    clf = RandomForestClassifier(100 , random_state = 10)
    clf.fit(data.values[: , 1:-4], custom_target)

    imps , features = zip(*sorted(zip(clf.feature_importances_, cols) , reverse = True))
    # store the results as you like
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed. Even I tried using RandomForest to find the influential features for each cluster but I think there's some mistake in my approach as I'm getting feature_importances_ value same(in my case 0) for all the features. Can you please tell the correct way of applying RandomForest to get the influential features for each cluster.